# I want to add a Page on my Website for Embedding the Youtube Videos just by Submitting the Embedding code in my site in php?

Tags: php, youtube

I want to add a Page on my Website for Embedding the Youtube Videos just by Submitting the Embedding code in my site in php . is there in free script for it.
Can anyone provide me the code for

Please help Me!

Rupali

Comment: This is a programming website

Answer (score 0):

Letting users to input the embedding HTML is **BAD PRACTICE**, and leaves a security hole in your web site. (Just imagine if some user enters some random HTML or an evil piece of JavaScript.)

The real solution would be to ask the user for the URL of the video and then constructing the embed HTML yourself. 
If you examine the youtube embedding HTMLs, you'll see it is not difficult.

Comment: Thanks.
But can you provide me the script for the same so that I can get an idea of how to work on this.